# Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.fineract.ServerApplication for gitlab-ci

Tags: java, gradle, gitlab-ci

When I build from my local machine with the following command `gradlew -p fineract-provider/ build` and copy the war file to my remote server, it runs normally with the command `java -Djava.awt.headless=false -jar fineract-provider.war` but when I run the same build command through my gitlab-CI, copy it automatically to the server and then run the same java command, I get a class not found exception as below:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.fineract.ServerApplication
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:58)
```

The above is exactly what it spits out to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fineract has a setting in the `gradle.build` that excludes the main classes. so I simply changed this

```
if (!(project.hasProperty('env') && project.getProperty('env') == 'dev')) {
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            exclude '**/Server*'
            exclude '**/MariaDB4j*'
            exclude '**/EmbeddedTomcatWithSSLConfiguration.java'
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            exclude '**/core/boot/tests/**'
        }
    }
}
}
```

to this

```
if (!(project.hasProperty('env') && project.getProperty('env') == 'dev')) {
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
//            exclude '**/Server*'
            exclude '**/MariaDB4j*'
            exclude '**/ServerWithMariaDB4jApplication.java'
//            exclude '**/EmbeddedTomcatWithSSLConfiguration.java'
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            exclude '**/core/boot/tests/**'
        }
    }
}
}
```